# Material Design EditText adds wrong padding

Tags: android, android-appcompat

layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="Label text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:text="Input tex"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Produces the following picture on pre-Lollipop as well as on Lollipop device.
How can I compensate the unnecessary padding of `EditText`?
I would add `android:paddingLeft` to label TextView, but I don't know which value should I specify.

[image]

Comment: I'll do that, but what padding value should I use? Is there a theme attribute for that?

Answer (score 2):

`Theme.AppCompat` uses `@drawable/abc_edit_text_material.xml` as `EditText` background. From the sources I see that it is an `InsetDrawable`. `InsetDrawable` has it own "paddings" - `@dimen/abc_control_inset_material`. To compensate these paddings, I add `android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abc_control_inset_material"` to label's `TextView`.

```
<TextView android:text="Label text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abc_control_inset_material"/>
```

I'm not sure this is a final answer, because it's not documented.

Answer (score 0):

Create several **dimens.xml** files, in different values-XY folders, where XY is an API Level, i.e.: `18`.

The actual values are taken from that file: `android:paddingRight="@dimen/...`

---

If you want to use the API Level - default values, then:

In the SDK folder, for each API Level, you'll find the dimens file in the values folder.
Take each of those files and copy them in your different values folders.